# How to hide only sender address while sending message by CDO using excel VBA

Tags: excel, email, cdo.message, vba

**Below image is interface of an email for indication**

[image]

I have browsed through the contents, but I didn't get any solution for this and still finding codes to populate this method but not succeed :( .

```
Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
Dim strBody As String
Dim Flds As Variant

Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

     iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
     Set Flds = iConf.Fields
      With Flds
         .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
         .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") _
                        = "SMTP server name"    
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update

End With

strBody = "Hello!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "" & vbNewLine & _
          "" & vbNewLine & _
          "Thanks" 

With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = "sam@gmail.com" 
    .CC = ""  
    .BCC = ""
    .From = """Jhon walker"" <jhon.walker@gmail.com>" 
    .Subject = "test"
    .TextBody = ""
    .send
End With
```

I will be thankful of any contribution.

Comment: What would be the point?

Comment: I just want to hide the **sender ID**, but not **user name** as indicating in attached snap. As you have been seen in many **outlook mails** that it shows only sender name instead of sender name & ID.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the email address from the .to line and place it in the .bcc line.  I haven't tested this.

Comment: not resolved :) still displaying both **sender name & ID**.

Comment: Thanks, for all of your contribution but I got my answer and it is very simple to hide only sender ID. I just need to use comma (**,**) between name & ID in my code then recipient cannot see my sender address on his screen except sender name when I use this trick `.From = """username"",<email@abc.com>"`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without testing I think what you're looking for is `.SentOnBehalfOfName`

Comment: No **.SentOnBehalfOfName** is another method. I want to send email from my **ID** but it should not display on screen except **name**, as often hidden in **Outlook**.